# BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter v5 fails - unable to cast object

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I have v5 of the BizTalk scheduled task adapter installed to test and live servers. It is configured to run with the following class - triggered every 2 minutes

> ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents.FileStreamProvider, ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa9f2dd0f13442dc

It is pointing at a local xml file

It works fine on the test environment but on the live environment the receive location shuts down after the first poll and the followed error is logged:

> The receive location "RcvScheduledTask_Loc" with URL "schedule://TimeSpan/GetEmail" is shutting down. Details:"Unable to cast object of type 'ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents.FileStreamProvider' to type 'ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents.IScheduledTaskStreamProvider'.".

On attempting to undeploy with the BTDF, the following error is wrriten to deploy results in response to a BTSTask RemoveApp:

> EXEC : warning : Could not validate TransportTypeData, Address or
>   Public Address properties for Receive Location 'RcvScheduledTask_Loc'.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Compare the configuration between test and live?  Are you sure the adapter was installed properly on live?

Comment: The msi for the adapter ran just fine on live - no errors in eventvwr. I'm using the BizTalk Deployment Framework and Powershell to deploy to test and promote to live. Configuration from a bindings perspective should be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the binding for receive location look for

```
<ReceiveLocationTransportTypeData>\<CustomProps>\<AdapterConfig>\<config>\<task>
```

Here you should find a  element. Problem was I'd forgotten update the version. After the update the content should read:

> ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents.FileStreamProvider,
>   ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents, Version=5.0.0.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa9f2dd0f13442dc

This problem was being masked on the Test server because v4 of the scheduled task adapter assemblies were still present in the GAC - along with the v5 assemblies

Comment: Confirmed same for us. We had different versions on different environments.  I found the installed version here: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ScheduledTaskAdapter.TaskComponents\v4.0_4.0.0.0__aa9f2dd0f13442dc